# Rewrite class with fopen and using curl instead in Laravel

Tags: php, curl

Really new in Laravel and I still trying to learn it so please help me a bit here. There is one class which pull data from another site. The problem is that it is using fopen but in matter of server security this function is off so it must use curl.

```
const CACHE_KEY = 'rate';
public static function getRate() {
    if (Cache::has(self::CACHE_KEY)) {
        return Cache::get(self::CACHE_KEY);
    }

    $oneHourTimestamp = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(1);
    $tenMinutesTimestamp = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);

    $page = trim(file_get_contents('https://example.com/'));
    $rates = json_decode($page, TRUE);
    if (!$rates) {
        Cache::put(self::CACHE_KEY, '-', $tenMinutesTimestamp);
        return '-';
    }

    $Rate = @$rates['1']['2'];
    if (!$Rate) {
        Cache::put(self::CACHE_KEY, '-', $tenMinutesTimestamp);
        return '-';
    }

    Cache::put(self::CACHE_KEY, $Rate, $oneHourTimestamp);
    return $usdRate;
}
```

UPDATE:

Like this?

```
function get_curl_content($url) {
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
  return $result;
}

const CACHE_KEY = 'rate';
public static function getRate() {
if (Cache::has(self::CACHE_KEY)) {
    return Cache::get(self::CACHE_KEY);
}

$oneHourTimestamp = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(1);
$tenMinutesTimestamp = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);   

$result = $this->get_curl_content('https://example.com/');
$rates = json_decode($result, TRUE);
if (!$rates) {
    Cache::put(self::CACHE_KEY, '-', $tenMinutesTimestamp);
    return '-';
}

$Rate = @$rates['1']['2'];
if (!$Rate) {
    Cache::put(self::CACHE_KEY, '-', $tenMinutesTimestamp);
    return '-';
}

Cache::put(self::CACHE_KEY, $Rate, $oneHourTimestamp);
return $usdRate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the contentos of a webpage with curl you can create this function and add it to your class:

```
function get_curl_content($url) {
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   return $result;
}
```

And you can change

```
$page = trim(file_get_contents('https://example.com/'));
```

for:

```
$page = $this->get_curl_content('https://example.com/');
```

Comment: And I must remove only this `$page = trim(file_get_contents('https://example.com/'));`? and this method inside the class?

Comment: Yes you can remove it and use the new method

Comment: If you change $url for $result in the json_decode, yes.

Comment: Sorry but doesn't update the info.. everything load as must but doesn't change the info

Comment: If you are going to use it in more controllers you can add the method in the Controller all your controllers extend, by default Laravel creates the Base controller in the App/Http/Controllers/Controller.php

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure I understand this :)

Comment: It's method inheritance, if your controller extends the base controller you can use the methods of the base controller like if them were from your class.

Comment: Ok, it was caching function. I've got `Next ErrorException: Undefined variable: result` ... here `$rates = json_decode($result, TRUE)`

Comment: Why is undefined? Isn't defined in the function?

Comment: If you use the code on your edited answer you are not defining any function, you assign to $result the value of th curl result.
You hav to add the function i answered to the class and use the function to addthe curl value to the $result variable.

Comment: I have edited again the current code in my question .. this is how it's look now and I get this undefined variable: result ... with `$rates = json_decode($result, TRUE);` result here

Comment: First you have to get the contents like `$result = $this->get_curl_content('https://example.com/');`

Comment: But why I need two times `https://example.com/` .. one time in the function and one time... after that .. I'm really lost

Comment: Ok, now you have the function declared, it takes the url as a parameter. 
Now, you have to send the contents of the page to the json_decode. So first you have to get the contents into the $result variable by calling the function, and then you can use it in the json_decode.

Comment: That's ok and I understand why I need `$url = 'https://www.example.com/';` but then I don't understand why I need `$result = $this->get_curl_content('https://example.com/');` when I assign `$result = curl_exec($curl);` .. sorry but I'm tottaly lost

Comment: So like this? Updated question.. I moved out the function into the class.. and then called `$result = $this->get_curl_content('https://example.com/');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113219/discussion-between-nil-llisterri-and-jordan-vit).